# cakePHP form not sending data to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

im struggling with my cake code(very new to cakephp) and was after some help. what is intended by my code is to get data from a form and when the person hits register it send data to my database but that is not happening, instead when i hit register the page is reloading. I'm currently using cake 2.0 and wamp server 2.2

here is the code for my add function from my individualscontroller.php

```
function addIndividual(){
    if($this->request->is('individuals')){
    {if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

} code here

and here is the code from my add_individual.ctp including the form

```
   <h2>Please enter your details</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('individuals', array('action'=>'addIndividual'));
echo $this->Form->input('Title: ');
echo $this->Form->input('First Name: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Surname: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Street Address: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Suburb: ');
echo $this->Form->input('State: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Country: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Email: ');
echo $this->Form->input('Password: ');
echo $this->Form->end('Click here to Register');

?>
```

EDIT - The name of the table im trying to insert data into is called individuals
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: check your model name and relation to database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addIndividual(){
if($this->request->is('individuals')){
if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }
}
}
```

Change this code to

```
function addIndividual(){
if($this->request->is('post')){
{if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }
}
}
```

Also please change your view file as follows.

```
<h2>Please enter your details</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Individual', array('action'=>'addIndividual'));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Title: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'First Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Surname: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Street Address: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Suburb: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'State: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Country: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Email: '));
echo $this->Form->input('FieldnameasinDB',array('label'=>'Password: '));
echo $this->Form->end('Click here to Register');

?>
```

Change the model like this

```
<?php class Individual extends AppModel{ var $name='Individual'; 
    public $useTable = 'tableName';
    public $primaryKey = 'userid';}
```

Comment: data from the form hasnt been saved in the table. :/

it proceeded to the index page but when i checked the tablein phpmyadmin, there was no record of what i inputted

Comment: @user1393064 can you please post your Model also?

Comment: <?php

class Individual extends AppModel{

 var $name='Individual';
 }

Comment: @user1393064 please post the complete model. Also have you created the model and controller using the cake bake tool or manually?

Comment: manually, that is all i have in my model. I was following an andrew perkins youtube tutorial, i havent added any validation to my page yet as im waiting for my forms to be stored in the table in my database.

Comment: @user1393064 updated the ans please change your view file code accordingly 'FieldnameasinDB' to the corresponding filedname as in database

Comment: still nothing going through to the database. the fields in the database are as follows

userid,title,firstname,surname,email,password,streetaddress,city,state,country,activated

Comment: i have changed the information in the ctp file to match the database, not including userid(should be autoassigned) and activated

Comment: have you changed the 'FieldnameasinDB' with the corresponding field name in the view file? before saving the data, in the controller please put a debug statement and what what value is it getting. `{if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {` change this to `{ debug($this->data); if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {`

Comment: please post the value from the debug to analyse further.

Comment: \app\Controller\IndividualsController.php (line 11)
array(
 'individuals' => array(
  'TITLE' => 'mr',
  'FIRSTNAME' => 'jarrad',
  'SURNAME' => 'hall',
  'EMAIL' => 'jtg987@hotmail.com',
  'PASSWORD' => 'qazwsx',
  'STREET' => '5 ridley',
  'CITY' => 'doncaster',
  'STATE' => 'victoria',
  'COUNTRY' => 'Australia'
 )
)


then i get a fatal error about saving because we took the code out

Comment: is your userid field is autoincrement? also please change the field name to small letters.

Comment: can you please paste your complete model, controller and the view file

Comment: <?php

class IndividualsController extends AppController{

 var $name ='individuals';
  function index(){
   $this->set('title_for_layout', 'indexPage');
  }
  function add_individual(){
if($this->request->is('post')){
{if (debug($this->data)); if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }
}
}
}
}

Comment: <h2>Please enter your details</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('individuals', array('action'=>'add_Individual'));
echo $this->Form->input('title',array('label'=>'Title: '));
echo $this->Form->input('firstname',array('label'=>'First Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('surname',array('label'=>'Surname: '));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>'Email: '));

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>'Password: '));
echo $this->Form->input('street',array('label'=>'Street Address: '));
echo $this->Form->input('city',array('label'=>'City: '));
echo $this->Form->input('state',array('label'=>'State: '));
echo $this->Form->input('country',array('label'=>'Country: '));
echo $this->Form->end('Click here to Register');
?>

Comment: <?php

class Individual extends AppModel{

 var $name='Individual';
 }


first post is the controller, post 2&3 is the view files and this is the model

Comment: @user1393064 updated the ans. Please use the Model as in the ans and change the tableName to the corresponding table name. Also use the controller as I have mentioned in the ans.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object for this line

{if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data))

Comment: have you changed the `public $useTable = 'tableName';` to the corresponding table name?

Comment: add this line before the save method `$this->Individual->create();`

Comment: before or after this statement 

if($this->request->is('post')?

Comment: @gvLearner Your example states $this->Form->create('individuals') but I think it should be $this->Form->create('Individual')  (ie: the model name). I couldn't edit your post because it was less than 6 characters and the system wouldn't let me.

Comment: after that satement. `function add_individual(){ 
  if($this->request->is('post')){ 
  {
   $this->Individual->create();
   if ($this->Individual->save($this->request->data)) 
   { 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved'); 
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
    } 
    else { 
    $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
    } 
   } 
  } 
 } `

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Comment: change the view file to this `echo $this->Form->create('Individual', array('action'=>'addIndividual'));`

Comment: Also please remove the `var $name ='individuals'; ` from controller

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0006 sec )

Comment: comment the `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));` line and see what query is it getting executing when saving the data.

Comment: Missing View
Error: The view for IndividualsController::add_Individual() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\wamp\www\jarrad\app\View\Individuals\add__individual.ctp

Comment: What was the view filename you have given. Make the view file name corresponding to the `addIndividual` method to `add__individual.ctp`

Comment: they are now passing into the database but i have these errors

Error: The view for IndividualsController::add_Individual() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: C:\wamp\www\jarrad\app\View\Individuals\add__individual.ctp

the files should be there

Comment: simple solution change the method name in the controller to `addindividual` and change the view file name to the same. please note there is no capital letter and underscore inbetween.

Comment: Good grief. Please place additional code as edits in your question and answer, not in the comments where it's a pain to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error in your code is in the line given below.

```
if($this->request->is('individuals'))
```

Here `$this->request->is` checks for the request type and you have assigned here `individuals` and this is not a request type. Request types are like `post`, 'put', 'ajax', 'GET' and others. So please check the method of your form and put it in `$this->request->is()`. Please look at this URL:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html